# Office add-in PowerPoint - store custom data to file not works

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint, office-js, office-addins

I want store my custom data to PowerPoint presentation file. I use this example: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Add-in-JavaScript-PersistCustomSettings

But I want store my data during Office add-in is unloading (for sample when user closing a presentation file).

So I use `window.onunload = function () {}...` for detect when presentation document start closing.

And during closing PowerPoint, the method:

```
Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync()
```

return error: `Saving failed. error: An internal error has occurred.`

Code sample

**Home.html**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="Home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="setData">Set data</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**Home.js**:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

   Office.initialize = function (reason) {
       $(document).ready(function () {

           console.log('>>> Office.initialize()');

            // TODO: If you wanted to save the settings stored in the app's property 
            // bag before the app is closed - for instance, for saving app state - 
            // add a handler to the Internet Explorer window.onunload event.
           window.onunload = function ()
           {
               saveSettingsToFile();
           };

           $('#setData').click(SetData);
        });
   };

   function SetData()
   {
       saveToPropertyBag('dataKey', 'myData');
   }

    // Stores the settings in the JavaScript APIs for Office property bag.
   function saveToPropertyBag(key, value)
   {
       // Note that Project does not support the settings object.
       // Need to check that the settings object is available before setting.
       if (Office.context.document.settings)
       {
           Office.context.document.settings.set(key, value);
       }
       else
       {
           console.log('Error: Feature not supported: the settings object is not supported in this host application');
       }
   }

   function saveSettingsToFile()
   {
       if (Office.context.document.settings) {
           Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync(
           function (asyncResult) {
               if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed)
               {
                   console.log('Saving failed. error: ' + asyncResult.error.message);
               }
               else {
                   console.log('Saving success');
               }
           });
       }
   }

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot leverage onunload event in this way. When the add-in is closed, so is it's connection to the document.

I would suggest calling `Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync()` from within the `saveToPropertyBag()` function. Unless you are constantly making changes to the property bag there shouldn't be much overhead to this. Alternatively, if you need make several changes in rapid succession you can call `saveAsync()` immediately following.

If a closed/closing event is of interest, there is currently a feature request in the ]Office Developer Platform UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/17572624-need-to-have-an-onclose-event-for-the-task-pane-or) that could use your vote. :)

Comment: thank you for clarification, onunload/onclose would good functional for store current app state.

Comment: The challenge here is onunload/onclose in your add-in occur after the connection between your add-in and the document has been torn down. At the moment there isn't a way to capture closing prior to that tear down happening.